# Flutter USB Dynamic Access

Tags: flutter

I am building a Flutter app to access certain folder (like usb_path/Media) of any OTG (Flash Drive) connected to my android device and display the contents of the folder. I tried many plugins and approaches but none of them worked. Any help would be great!

Tried many plugins but some of them dont work at all and some of them don't work as intended.